# Changing Magento Server and MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Someone asked me to move a magento website, I have loads of experience of moving wordpress and joomla websites, found a few tutorials through Google and started the process as it seemed similar.

Backed up DB
Backed up Source files
Built new DB
FTP'd source files to new server (with the same domain)
changed config (local.xml)
Imported MySQL

but as soon as I hit this bit of code in the MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `admin_rule`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ADMIN_RULE_ROLE_ID_ADMIN_ROLE_ROLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `admin_role` (`role_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

It errors, and with every similar query after it, the MySQL was directly exported from PHPmyadmin.

This is the error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'cl50-occasions.#sql-5a23_1f2e7e2' (errno: 121)
```

As with every phpmyadmin generated query after it of a similar nature.

The website seems to of pulled through all content but non of the old styling/layout/CSS. I am not sure if this is related but I am hoping it is. Can anyone guide me as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Use the built in back-up tool to export the db dump. This way you avoid issues like the one you have. `System->Tools->Backup`

Comment: I have numerous back-ups of the database.

Comment: You said "the MySQL was directly exported from PHPmyadmin.". Don't do that. Use the tool I suggested.

Comment: I think the Database has been deleted already... :/ I did it as a favour for someone because they went out of business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download a new Magento from source. Be sure to get the same version
   as the previous.
2. Install it to the new location.
3. Empty the database keeping the structure
4. import there the old database's data only (not the structure - cut it from the file).
5. Upload your old files over the new ones.. you can do it faster with a tarball and an ssh
   access. Actually only some directories should be necessary, but do them all to be sure. You can surely avoid `/var/cache` and `/var/session` that have many files.
6. Modify now your `local.xml` to the new database access.
7. In the `core_config_data` table, adjust the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` values from the old ones, and you are online.